# Can the train_test_split be replaced from sklearn.model_selection?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

Can this call be replaced with

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

Comment: Well, did you try both and get any error or what?

Answer (score 1):

If your question is if both codes does the same job, then yes. Use the second one where you import train_test_split, makes the code more simple to read and understand.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).